# Displaying NMEA data in text console

Tags: data-transmission, gps, data-storage

I'm using an ublox EVK M8T and I'm trying to make a script that displays in text console in real time the data from NMEA and also the time marker from when an event happens. Is there a possibility to display either the rising or falling edge value of tm2 or do someone have any documentation on how to do it since it in text console the tm2 is being displayed in a hex format? I've tried an implementation in matlab and pyth , both unsuccessful at the moment.
[image]

```
 Packet Console  
        09:53:52  L -> UBX CFG,  Size   9,  'Config'
        09:53:53  L -> NMEA GPRMC,  Size  64,  'Recommended Minimum Specific GNSS Data'
        09:53:53  L -> NMEA GPGGA,  Size  65,  'Global Positioning System Fix Data'
        09:53:53  L -> NMEA GPGLL,  Size  52,  'Geographic Position - Latitude/Longitude'
        09:53:53  L -> UBX CFG,  Size   9,  'Config'
        09:53:53  L -> UBX-TIM-TM2, Size 14,  'Time Mark 2'

    Text console

        09:54:05  $GPGLL,4420.99497,N,02601.85621,E,095405.15,A,A*65
    09:54:06  $GPRMC,095406.12,A,4420.99496,N,02601.85609,E,,,221118,,,,A*78
        09:54:06  $GPGGA,095406.12,4420.99496,N,02601.85609,E,1,,,128.5,M,,M,,*51
    09:54:06  $GPGLL,4420.99496,N,02601.85609,E,095406.12,A,A*6A
        09:54:07  $GPRMC,095407.16,A,4420.99495,N,02601.85599,E,,,221118,,,,A*74
    09:54:07  $GPGGA,095407.16,4420.99495,N,02601.85599,E,1,,,128.6,M,,M,,*5E
        09:54:07  $GPGLL,4420.99495,N,02601.85599,E,095407.16,A,A*66
    09:54:08  $GPRMC,095408.13,A,4420.99494,N,02601.85592,E,,,221118,,,,A*74
        09:54:08  $GPGGA,095408.13,4420.99494,N,02601.85592,E,1,,,128.7,M,,M,,*5F
    09:54:08  $GPGLL,4420.99494,N,02601.85592,E,095408.13,A,A*66
        09:54:09  $GPRMC,095409.15,A,4420.99493,N,02601.85591,E,,,221118,,,,A*77
```

Comment: Couple of questions: What's your background/skill level?  What (broadly speaking) is the u-blox module going to be used for?

Comment: I've just started working with ublox , so my skill level is pretty basic. Broadly speaking I have to make a script so that when I use a switch button for example , the tm2 would appear in text console with the specific info.Just using it to compare and validate the data between ublox and another gps that would be used for a rocket.

Comment: I'd look into using an Arduino-based system to do the parsing, etc. especially if you have no prior programming experience.  A number of ready-to-use software libraries are available (for talking to the GPS) and the platform is designed to be friendly to new or inexperienced users.  Have you coded at all in C++, Python, or something similar?

Comment: I have experience in C++. Also I've tried to make a script in matlab, but it does not recognize my COM port no matter what I do. When I establish the serial comm using putty the COM works without a problem, displaying the values in text console. So what you want to say is that I would somehow need to connect the ublox to an arduino so that it should act like a "man in the middle" between ublox and the pc? If so, I actually have an rapberry pi model 3 b , but I don't know if would be the same thing.

Comment: What I'd recommend doing is to use an Arduino platform sitting between the GPS and your PC to convert the binary messages into a text-based format.  The text-based format doesn't have to be anything standardized, just something you can easily parse (I recommend tab-delimited values with the first column containing the message type).  You can then do further processing on the PC side.  I haven't used a RasPi in this type of application but note that those are usually used as embedded Linux systems and you want something simpler and more low-level.  ...

Comment: ... I personally like the [Teensy 3.5/3.6](https://www.pjrc.com/store/index.html) boards (they have a fast CPU, a decent amount of RAM and PROM, a µSD slot, and include a single-precision FPU) but another option might work better for you.

Comment: That seems ike a nice choice. I've already received an raspberry pi as a present and I was thinking of maybe using it to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to space exploration

Comment: @pericynthion The OP mentioned (in the comments) that this is for a rocketry application but yea, it is rather.

Comment: No rocket with a ublox GPS is going to go to space, and besides it would be off-topic even if it were for a space application...

Comment: Can anyone suggest a SE site that this could be migrated to?  Maybe GIS?

Comment: Judging by the comment @uhoh left on my answer, maybe Electronics would be a good fit.

Comment: @AlexandruLapusneanu I've also voted to close but I am glad you were able to get some help here in the interim. Isn't this a perfect match for Stack Overflow? In fact, you have a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469455/3904031) there already. I think the thing to do would be to put some work into updating that question based on (and linked to) information in the [answer here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33208/12102). The more details you can add there about *what you have tried already* and why it isn't sufficient, the more likely it will be you get a helpful answer.

Comment: @AlexandruLapusneanu after a half-day you can make a substantial edit again, and that will bump it up in the *active question* queue so more people will see it. There is [Geographic Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) as well, you can check to see if similar questions get answers there, but I think SO is the right place. I also recommend that once you post there you "babysit" the question and respond quickly to comments (like 60 seconds) as long as it seems productive.

Comment: You should also describe what you've learned in the [u-blox forum](https://forum.u-blox.com/) and [product-resources](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product-resources) pages. One comment like "why haven't you read the documentation first?" can stop many users from taking your question seriously, and can attract down votes. SO is a more challenging space to ask than Space SE, though it's getting a bit better these days. See also https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/u-center

Comment: Add a partial script, example, anything that shows you have put in some effort first before asking. So I'd say don't worry about migrating this question. Put your time and energy into improving your [SO question] and include description of all your work and possibly links to the answer here.

Comment: @uhoh I went through exactly what the OP described when I first learned how to interface with GPSes.  It can be very confusing at first if you don't know what you should be looking for.  `+1` on your above comment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages being displayed on the console are NMEA, a plain ASCII text format (not hexadecimal).  To do anything further with them you'll either need to write software yourself to interpret it or use 3<sup>rd</sup>-party software to do so.  I've done both myself in both Perl and C++ and it was very simple and straightforward to do ([here](https://www.quaxio.com/arduino_gps/) is a random example of doing it by hand in C++).  Often-times you can you use (or adapt) an existing software library to do the parsing (the [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) library for ublox / Arduino is one such option).

All of the common NMEA messages have been standardized with **[this page](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/)** widely considered to be the definitive guide.  Some vendors include custom NMEA messages; for these you'll need to refer to devices' manufacturers who should provide device-specific manuals.  In your case, the document you want is [**u-blox 8 / u-blox M8 Receiver Description (including Protocol Specification)**, UBX-13003221](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28UBX-13003221%29_Public.pdf).

In some cases, manufacturers offer their own, proprietary formats in addition to NMEA.  To use these you will typically need to send a specific NMEA message *to* the GPS.  The various vendor-specific proprietary formats often provide access to features or data not provided through the NMEA protocol.  u-blox does this with their binary UBX protocol and the  manual linked above describes how to use it (starting on p. 134).  The format of the proprietary `UBX-TIM-TM2` message (available only via UBX, not NMEA), for example, can be found on page 364 of that guide.  Unlike the text-based NMEA protocol, you will need to use software to parse the UBX messages (the raw data isn't in human-readable form).  The NeoGPS library mentioned above has partial UBX support.  Another option is to forgo libraries entirely; [here](https://github.com/PaulZC/NEO-M8T_GNSS_FeatherWing), for example, is an Arduino (or Linux/Unix, both platforms are supported) program that specifically supports the UBX protocol and the `UBX-TIM-TM2` message; being C++ or Python it ought to be easily adaptable to other platforms.  Other UBX libraries likely exist.

---

You say that, at least initially, you simply want to get data from the GPS onto your PC for further processing.  What I'd recommend doing is to use an Arduino platform sitting between the GPS and your PC to convert the binary messages into a text-based format. The text-based format doesn't have to be anything standardized, just something you can easily parse (I recommend tab-delimited values with the first column containing the message type). You can then do further processing on the PC side. I don't recommend using, e.g., a Raspberry Pi in this type of application since those are usually used as embedded Linux systems and you want something simpler and more low-level. I personally like the [Teensy 3.5/3.6 boards](https://www.pjrc.com/store/index.html) (no affiliation, [tech specs here](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/techspecs.html)); they have a fast CPU, a generous amount of RAM and PROM, a µSD slot, and include a single-precision FPU.  That's my favorite but another option might work better for you.

Before exploring Arduino options though, I'd suggest taking a quick look to see whether the aforementioned [Python program](https://github.com/PaulZC/NEO-M8T_GNSS_FeatherWing/blob/master/Python/NEO-M8T_GNSS_RAWX_Logger.py) can be adapted for your application.  If you have have access to a Linux system (even the Raspberry Pi you mentioned having might suffice) this could save you a hassle (a Windows machine might also work but that platform appears to be poorly supported).  Note that I'm referring here to logging to disk, not acting as a real-time translator/bridge (the previously-discussed Arduino option).

Comment: @AlexandruLapusneanu That was fast!  I hadn't even finished editing it.

Comment: If you like GPS questions, these could both use a 2nd answer [How to detect potentially poor antenna placement from GPS data?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/413621/102305) and [What exactly does C/No (dBHz) mean in u-Blox GPS data?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/413624/102305)

Comment: @uhoh I'll take a look.

Comment: @AlexHajnal could you provide mewith contact info in case that I have other questions?

Comment: @AlexandruLapusneanu I'm far from an expert on these things.  If you need clarification post a comment on this question and I'll see if I can help.  Better though would be to post a new question over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @AlexHajnal I'm still confused on how to exactly do the work so I've just wanted to know if I understood. Isn't there a possibility to exctart the data without using a development board, just through the usb connection between the pc and the gps?(maybe by using a matlab or python scrip)?

Comment: @AlexandruLapusneanu I believe you should be able to adapt the Python program I mentioned to do it.  That program expects a serial port (either real or emulated).  I'm not familiar with ublox GPSes but typically you'll need a driver on the PC to emulate a serial port over USB (presuming the ublox presents a USB serial port); you'll see it as e.g. `COM1` (Windows) or `/dev/ttyUSB0` (Linux). I've only worked with GPSes with physical serial ports (a.k.a. UARTs) though. I would strongly suggest asking for more info on Stack Overflow; the folks there should be able to assist much better than I can.